# Terraform: How to get the VPC CIDR from VPC id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to source the **PIV4_CIDR** for a given VPC, using the aws_vpcs data-source to identify the VPC first and get the CIDR from ID - is it possible?

Just a bit of background, for some design reason, we have services in different VPC. Say, eg. I have three VPCs: `xxxprod-n`, `xxxprod-l` and `xxxprod-h` and I want to add a SG rule for the entire subnet to allow access to a specific port. This is what I tried:

```
data "aws_vpcs" "prod" {
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}prd-*"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "pa-allow" {
  count             = length(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8140
  to_port           = 8140
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [sort(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)[count.index].cidr_block]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.secg.id
  description       = "allow from ${sort(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)[count.index]}"
}
```

I get the error:

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on ../../modules/mgt/ec2.tf line 42, in resource
>   "aws_security_group_rule" "pa-allow":   42:   cidr_blocks       =
>   [sort(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)[count.index].cidr_block]
>
> This value does not have any attributes.

I tried that, based on this page: `https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html`, thinking *aws_vpc* and *aws_vpcs* will do similar sort of thing but it seem doesn't. Any idea how do I do that?

Comment: I do not think you need to use `sort` here. Also, this looks like 0.12 syntax. Is that correct?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes, that's 0.12 syntax, which I'm using atm. I believe the syntax is correct, in theory, but may not be the correct attributes.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, re, `sort`, the thing is `data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids` is a *set*, rather than a *list*, hence the elements are not in a particular order and therefore cannot be accessed by numeric index as in list. I used sort to go around that issue.

Comment: According to the documentation it is a list: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpcs.html#attributes-reference

Comment: I get error about saying the ‘record-set doesn’t have any indices’ if I don’t use sort and only time it works (e.g the Description parameter) if I use sort. The doc probably used the word ‘list’ as a generic term?

Comment: Anyway, going back to my original problem, it still doesn’t work with it without sort; the error doesn’t actually complain about ‘sort’ but attributes and i’m Still looking for solution. Any help very much appreciated!!

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is I do not believe `cidr_block` is an exported attribute for the VPC ID according to the documentation. There may be other issues, but that would be a showstopper right there.

Comment: I'm sort of thinking the same but as `aws_vpc`, which returns info about a single VPC, has that as an attribute, I thought probably it's gonna work the similar way for the *aws_vpcs* list element. So the next question is, how do I achieve that. Not necessarily I have to use aws_vpcs, but as long as I can retrieve the associated CIDR.

Comment: Do you have multiple VPCs that match those tags? If not you should use the singular `aws_vpc` data source and simplify the whole thing.

Comment: as I mentioned above, it will match two to three VPCs, per project according to our design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `SET`(not list) of vpcs using data.aws_vpcs. (I think the document is wrong...)
Then you can get data.aws_vpc list using data.aws_vpcs, and you can get cidr blocks of them.

```
data "aws_vpcs" "prod" {
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}prd-*"
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "prod" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)
  id    = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)[count.index]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "pa-allow" {
  count             = length(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8140
  to_port           = 8140
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [data.aws_vpc.prod[count.index].cidr_block]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.secg.id
  description       = "allow from ${tolist(data.aws_vpcs.prod.ids)[count.index]}"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As for today, you don't need to use the list approach anymore, it is not specified in the documentation but you can do something like this:

```
data "aws_vpc" "main" {
  id = <your_vpc_id>
}
```

And then you can access it `data.aws_vpc.main.cidr_block`, it is not specified in the [attributes referece](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc#attributes-reference), but it is there.

Terraform version: 1.0.11

AWS Provider version: 4.9.0